# Interrupt file upload when some condition is not true

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to implement this: while uploading a file check file extension if it's not .zip, the upload will be interrupted and a message is showed to the user so i wrote this:

```
// Implement both receiver that saves upload in a file and
// listener for successful upload
class ReportUploader implements Receiver, SucceededListener {
    public File file;

    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
        // Create upload stream
        FileOutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
        String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");

        String ext = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
        System.out.println("+++++++++++>" + ext);  
        if (!ext.equals(".zip")) {
            Notification.show("Could not upload file", Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return null;
        }
        try {
            file = new File(userHome + "/uploads/report/" + filename);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            Notification.show("Could not open file", e.getMessage(), Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return null;
        }
        return fos; 
    }

    public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
        String filename;
        String basepath;
        String folderName;
        String uploadDir;

        filename = event.getFilename();
        basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        uploadDir = Utilities.getProperty("uploadDir", basepath + "/WEB-INF/properties/config.properties"); 
        file = new File(uploadDir + filename);
        folderName = filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 5);

        Utilities.unZipFolder(uploadDir + filename, uploadDir + folderName);
        addFilename(folderName);

        try {
            Utilities.deleteCompressedReport(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Notification.show("upload finished", Notification.TYPE_HUMANIZED_MESSAGE); 
    }

    private void addFilename(String sFilename) {
        reportDirList.add(sFilename);
        selectDir.addItem(sFilename);
    }
}
```

When the extension is not .zip, this error is accrued:

```
com.vaadin.server.UploadException: Upload failed
at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.streamToReceiver(FileUploadHandler.java:581)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleFileUploadValidationAndData(FileUploadHandler.java:419)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.doHandleSimpleMultipartFileUpload(FileUploadHandler.java:382)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleRequest(FileUploadHandler.java:267)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1329)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:236)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.vaadin.server.NoOutputStreamException
at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.streamToReceiver(FileUploadHandler.java:518)
... 22 more
```

So How to interrupt upload and show the message?

Answer (score 4):

As you found, you need to call Upload's interruptUpload method. Some other points:

- Your Receiver is returning null after showing an error. I find that that leads to a stack trace in the logs, and part of the stack trace is even visible to the user if the user hovers the mouse over the Upload component. The way I avoid that is by returning a NullOutputStream instead of null.
- You may also want to protect against an exception (again, generates a stack trace) in receiveUpload if the user tries to upload without first selecting a file. Check for the empty filename, show an error, then return NullOutputStream.

  Here's an example receiveUpload, which has the above two protections. (Note: *Utilities.showError* just creates the usual Vaadin Notification dialog, nothing magic there.)

  ```
      public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
      if (filename != null && !filename.isEmpty()) {
          // Create upload stream
          FileOutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
          try {
              // Open the file for writing.
              file = new File(FileHandler.DEST_PATH + filename);
              fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
              return fos;
          } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
              Utilities.showError("Could not open file<br>", e.getMessage());
          }
      } else {
          Utilities.showError("You must first select a spreadsheet file to upload.");
      }
      uploadControl.interruptUpload();
      return new NullOutputStream(); // to prevent a stack trace from being thrown by Vaadin
  }
  ```
- In addition, you may want a StartedListener as well. That's the easiest place to check for a file being too big-- you may not want to allow someone to slam you with a gigabyte file. That uploadStarted method might look something like this:

  ```
  public void uploadStarted(StartedEvent event) {
      if (event.getFilename().isEmpty()) {
          uploadControl.interruptUpload();
          Utilities.showError("You must first select a file to upload.");
      } else if (event.getContentLength() > FileHandler.MAX_UPLOAD_BYTES) {
          uploadControl.interruptUpload();
          Utilities.showError("File is too big. Please check that you selected the correct file.");
      } else if (!FileHandler.isValidUploadMIMEType(event.getMIMEType())) {
          uploadControl.interruptUpload();
          Utilities.showError("Unexpected file type. Please check that you selected the correct file.");
      } else {
          progressBar.setValue(0.0f);
          progressBar.setVisible(true);
      }
  }
  ```

The one downside to this approach is that I'm avoiding the stack traces by avoiding exceptions. Which is fine but the Upload component clears the offending filename. If you throw exceptions you see the stack trace, but the user can see the file that they picked and maybe figure out what they did wrong. I decided this was minor.

Answer (score 1):

the solution :

Implement com.vaadin.ui.Upload.StartedListener.andget the filename which has the extension. If the extension is not valid  call the method interruptUpload() on the Upload component.